# reading 32bit variables from char buffer

Tags: javascript, c++

In  script below I sent through websocket two 32-bit variables to Server(visual c++):

```
     var buf = new Uint32Array(2);
     buf[0]=32bitVar1; 
     buf[1]=32bitVar2;
     ws.send(buf.buffer);
```

Server side receives this data, decodes it and keeps it in decoded char buffer:

```
     unsigned char decoded[maxSize];
```

How can i properly read those 32bit variables from char buffer and save them in unsigned int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `memcpy` to copy from `decoded` to some new variable or cast `decoded` to `unsigned int *myvals` and the first value should be in `myvals[0]` and 2nd in `myvals[1]` (as long as the CPU is the same endianness on both ends.